# How can I solve kubectl error while using micro-onos(with kind)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kind, onos

Hello I'm trying to use micro-onos.
Now I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and to use micro-onos I've installed kind, kubectl(with snap), and helm(with brew)

I tried with kubectl commands before, and I thought I got success message.
Next is following messages and result.

kubectl create namespace micro-onos
with next result:
namespace/micro-onos created

kubectl -n micro-onos get pods -w
Name                                            Ready   STATUS      RESTARTS    AGE
onos-cli-6b8d89f94-wbg55                        0/1 ContainerCreating   0       0s
onos-umbrella-topo-discovery-5b8cf447f40whhnh   0/1 ContainerCreating   0       0s

But today, I tried again, with the same command but error occurs like following.
I did nothing more, but error occurs
mir@ubuntu:~$ kubectl -n micro-onos get pods -w
E1115 12:34:45.398243   11311 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
E1115 12:34:45.398446   11311 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
E1115 12:34:45.400070   11311 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
E1115 12:34:45.400161   11311 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
E1115 12:34:45.401586   11311 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:45225 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I've searched in stack overflow, and I get error message like followings with next command:
mir@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get nodes -v=10
I1115 12:34:37.949126   11249 loader.go:395] Config loaded from file:  /home/mir/.kube/config
I1115 12:34:37.949838   11249 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a8a1abc" 'https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s'
I1115 12:34:37.950201   11249 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:45225 failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.950219   11249 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I1115 12:34:37.950223   11249 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1115 12:34:37.950234   11249 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1115 12:34:37.950294   11249 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.950318   11249 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.950353   11249 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a8a1abc" 'https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s'
I1115 12:34:37.950448   11249 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:45225 failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.950461   11249 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I1115 12:34:37.950465   11249 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1115 12:34:37.950468   11249 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1115 12:34:37.950483   11249 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.951961   11249 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.951996   11249 shortcut.go:100] Error loading discovery information: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.952074   11249 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a8a1abc" 'https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s'
I1115 12:34:37.952181   11249 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:45225 failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.952196   11249 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I1115 12:34:37.952200   11249 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1115 12:34:37.952203   11249 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1115 12:34:37.952216   11249 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.952226   11249 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.952253   11249 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a8a1abc" -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" 'https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s'
I1115 12:34:37.952299   11249 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:45225 failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.952311   11249 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I1115 12:34:37.952315   11249 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1115 12:34:37.952317   11249 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1115 12:34:37.952324   11249 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.953453   11249 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.954185   11249 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a8a1abc" 'https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s'
I1115 12:34:37.954374   11249 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:45225 failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.954504   11249 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I1115 12:34:37.954518   11249 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1115 12:34:37.954522   11249 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1115 12:34:37.954546   11249 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.954557   11249 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
I1115 12:34:37.954610   11249 helpers.go:264] Connection error: Get https://127.0.0.1:45225/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:45225: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:45225 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I reboot, reinstall kubectl, search for stack overflow and googles.
I've tried from the first step from formatting, and reinstall the ubuntu either.
It has the same problem in 22.04 and 20.04 either.

I wonder What is the problem. Can I get any ideas to solve it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the various outputs as plain text?  Don't forget to also include a [mcve] – what code did you write and deploy before running these `kubectl` commands?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I edit it.
I didn't did anything more, I just suspended my vmware image, and restarted it.